# Nuxt public folder as binded mount docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js, docker-volume

I deploy a Nuxt 3 app and I need to serve static files (external from the git repo) by public folder.

To do that I bind a docker volume like this :

```yaml
    volumes:
      - "${MEDIA_DIR}/music:/app/.output/public/music"  # for front access
      - "${MEDIA_DIR}/music:/app/public/music"          # for back access
```

Music/ folders & files permissions are 755, www-data:www-data on the host & root:root in the docker container.

The problem is, I can't access files from url domain.com/files.mp3 (404)
It works when I add files.mp3 directly in the public folder in the repo so there's no network miss-configuration.

Also when I dig inside the container app, I can list files.mp3 in the public folders.

So why nuxt cant serve these static files ?
Is there a better way to use external static files as assets in a nuxt 3 deployed app ?

Comment: Are the rights on the files the same when mounted and when coming from the image (showing an `ls -l` in an [edit] of your question could help here).

Comment: Hi β.εηοιτ,
I check the permissions, all folder are in 755 ww-data:ww-data on the host and root:root in the docker container.
I try with 777, same problem so I dont think its a file permissions problem.